# How to display quantity in select box in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How to change the Product Quantity to a Dropdown in WooCommerce

WooCommerce by default adds a quantity input box to your product pages where customers can enter quantities, but a lot of times you want to have more control over the quantities and make it more idiot proof on your site for customers by allowing them to select the quantities instead of entering it themselves.

Comment: I am pretty sure that quantity inputs are number type inputs, so that's already about 75% idiot proof in that people cannot enter letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function woocommerce_quantity_input($data = null) {

  global $product;

  if (!$data) {
    $defaults = array(
      'input_name'    => 'quantity',
      'input_value'   => '1',
      'max_value'     => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', '', $product ),
      'min_value'     => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', '', $product ),
      'step'          => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_step', '1', $product ),
      'style'         => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_style', 'float:left;', $product )
    );
  } else {
    $defaults = array(
      'input_name'    => $data['input_name'],
      'input_value'   => $data['input_value'],
      'max_value'     => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', '', $product ),
      'min_value'     => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', '', $product ),
      'step'          => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_step', '1', $product ),
      'style'         => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_style', 'float:left;', $product )
    );
  }

  if ( ! empty( $defaults['min_value'] ) )
    $min = $defaults['min_value'];
  else $min = 1;

  if ( ! empty( $defaults['max_value'] ) )
    $max = $defaults['max_value'];
  else $max = 20;

  if ( ! empty( $defaults['step'] ) )
    $step = $defaults['step'];
  else $step = 1;

  $options = '';

  for ( $count = $min; $count <= $max; $count = $count+$step ) {
    $selected = $count === $defaults['input_value'] ? ' selected' : '';
    $options .= '<option value="' . $count . '"'.$selected.'>' . $count . '</option>';
  }

  echo '<div class="quantity_select" style="' . $defaults['style'] . '"><select name="' . esc_attr( $defaults['input_name'] ) . '" title="' . _x( 'Qty', 'Product quantity input tooltip', 'woocommerce' ) . '" class="qty">' . $options . '</select></div>';

}
```